# How to trigger an action inside another action? Next Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to implement the logic to authorize the user when the page loads. Initially, I wanted to check if the token was in the cookies (`checkUserToken`) and if it was or was not - call another function (`fetchUserData`), which in the future would make a request to the server. Finally, when the server responded - call a third function (`setUserData`), which would fill `userData` with user data

```js
'use client'

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getCookie } from '@/app/untils/Cookies';

const initialState = {
  userData: null
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    checkUserToken: ()  => {
      console.log('chekc')
      const token = getCookie('user-token');
      console.log(token)
      if (token)
        return fetchUserData(token)
      else
        return fetchUserData(false)
    },
    fetchUserData: async (state, action) => dispatch => {
      return  console.log('FETCH')
      // console.log(state)
      // console.log(action)
    },
    setUserData: (state, action) => {
      console.log('SET USER')
      console.log(action)
      console.log(state)
    }
  }
})

export const { checkUserToken, fetchUserData, setUserData } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

How can I implement something like this in my slice?

Comment: Reducer functions are pure functions, they don't do side-effects like dispatching actions. `checkUserToken` can't dispatch any actions, and `fetchUserData` can't return a function value. Can you [edit] to explain what you are really trying to accomplish so we can then direct you to the correct Redux methodology?

Comment: @DrewReese Oh, thank you.

Actually, I want to implement the logic to authorize the user when the page loads.
Initially, I wanted to check if the token was in the cookies (checkUserToken) and if it was or was not - call another function (fetchUserData), which in the future would make a request to the server.
Finally, when the server responded - call a third function (setUserData), which would fill userData with user data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducer functions are pure functions, they don't do side-effects like dispatching actions. `checkUserToken` can't dispatch any actions, and `fetchUserData` can't return a function value. It appears to me that `checkUserToken` and `fetchUserData` are actually asynchronous actions. Create a [thunk action](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) for these.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getCookie } from '@/app/untils/Cookies';

export const checkUserToken = createAsyncAction(
  "userData/checkUserToken",
  (_, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log('check');
    const token = getCookie('user-token');
    console.log(token);
    
    return thunkAPI.dispatch(fetchUserData(token ?? false));
  },
);

export const fetchUserData = createAsyncAction(
  "userData/fetchUserData",
  async (token, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      console.log('FETCH');
      ... asynchronous fetching logic ...
      return /* some data??? */
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error));
    }
  },
);

const initialState = {
  userData: null,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUserData: (state, action) => {
      console.log('SET USER');
      ....
    }
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchUserData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // update the user data with returned action.payload value
      })
      .addCase(fetchUserData.rejected, (state, action) => {
        // set any error state, if necessary
      });
  },
})

export const { setUserData } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Note that it would be trivial for the `fetchUserData` action to access the cookies/token directly, and that the `fetchUserData.fulfilled` reducer case can set/update the user data state as well. This means that `setUserData` and `checkUserToken` actions are likely unnecessary.